# How to increase speed performance in Nuxt with SSR

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

How we can increase the speed performance in Nuxt with SSR for the following points.

- Reduce unused JavaScript
- Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern
- Minimize main-thread work
- Reduce JavaScript execution time
- Avoid enormous network payloads

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty generic questions, so let's go point by point:

- Reduce unused JavaScript: you can tree-shake your code (+3rd party) + lazy load your routes + [components](https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components#lazy-loading-your-components) (Nuxt does that nicely)
- Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern: the [modern property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-modern#the-modern-property) is nice for that
- Minimize main-thread work: beware of the heavy 3rd party scripts, like Google Analytics/GTM, heavy chats, heavy operations etc. Using a Service worker can help, other you could also try [Partytown](https://github.com/nuxt-community/partytown-module)
- Reduce JavaScript execution time: same, depends of your code here. More analysis of it will be required
- Avoid enormous network payloads: check if you're making huge amounts of HTTP calls or loading big 5MB of i18n JSON files

As always, you cannot have a quick and simple answer on that kind of subject.  You either need a performance expert or debug/learn it yourself.
This is a [nice start](https://web.dev/learn/), you could get quite a lot of explanations regarding core web vitals.

This [frontend checklist](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/01/front-end-performance-2021-free-pdf-checklist/) is always a nice article to read too.

---

PS: also if the matter is mostly SSR, it may come down to have a better infrastructure on the backend, with bulkier VPS server, some improved DB, maybe some Elasticsearch, some cache etc etc... (all the usual things you can improve on the backend)

Answer (score 1):

For speed optimization, we need to follow the following steps.

- Need to optimize the images
- Use shouldPreload in the render function nuxt.config.js
- Use compressor: shrinkRay(), for compression
- Use dns-prefetch for Google fonts
- Use minify js and css
- optimize API queries

Comment: You can even host your own google fonts, even better. Nuxt minifies the code already by default, did you needed some extra work there.

Answer (score 0):

For improving Nuxt website performance you can use nuxt-delay-hydration module, which will reduce the total blocking time and increase the performance of the nuxt website.

I have used Mount mode, which stops third party scripts(excluded the scripts used in pages and components i.e essential for your application) to load until hydration is complete.

Step 1. add  nuxt-delay-hydration in modules section in your nuxt.config.ts
Step 2. [delayHydration: {
mode: 'mount',
// enables nuxt-delay-hydration in dev mode for testing
debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
},](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sqN7.png)

Comment: This is not really solving the issue as stated in the project. Use some [real solution](https://roe.dev/blog/nuxt-server-components) rather.