# why nuxt app is to slow in phon, vuetify ,how can I increment performance on phone

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

hi I have nuxt app it work good and fast in **pc** but in **phone** is to slow I use vuetify in my app And I'm suspicious of this :) (The reason for the slowness of app is vuetify)
It seems to involve RAM and CPU, and because the phone is weaker, it slows down drastically.
how can I increment performance on phone .
for example it load 1s in  pc but in phone it load 4s
and if it load 5s in pc in phone load 14s

is is my nuxt.config

```js
export default {
  ssr: false,

  loadingIndicator: '~/static/html/loading.html',

  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s | ****',
    title: '****',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'fa',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  css: [
    '@/static/fonts/Ter/css/style.css',
    '@/static/css/main.css',
    '@/static/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.css',
  ],

  plugins: [
    {
      src: '@/plugins/drag.js',
      ssr: false,
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/ft.js',
      ssr: false,
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/particles',
      ssr: false,
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/axios.js',
      ssr: false,
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/lang.js',
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/vuetify.js',
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/Analytics.js',
      ssr: true,
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/Carousel3d.js',
      ssr: true,
    },
    {
      src: '@/plugins/EventBus.js',
    },
  ],

  components: true,

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
    '@nuxtjs/robots',
    'nuxt-i18n',
  ],

  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'fa',
    lazy: true,
    langDir: '~/langs',
    locales: [
      { code: 'en', name: 'english', iso: 'en-US', file: 'en.js', dir: 'ltr' },
      { code: 'fa', name: 'پارسی', iso: 'fa-IR', file: 'fa.js', dir: 'rtl' },
      { code: 'ar', name: 'العربی', iso: 'ar-QA', file: 'ar.js', dir: 'rtl' },
    ],
  },

  robots: {
    UserAgent: '*',
    Disallow: '/dashboard',
  },

  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://****/',
    exclude: ['/forget-password'],
  },

  axios: {
    // baseURL: 'https://****/api/',
    // baseURL: 'https://****/api/',
    baseURL: 'http://****/api/',
    headers: {
      common: {
        customer: 'true',
      },
    },
  },

  env: {
    baseURL: 'http://****/',
    selfURL: 'https://****/',
    cookieURL: 'localhost',
  },

  build: {
    html: {
      minify: {
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        decodeEntities: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        processConditionalComments: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        trimCustomFragments: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeEmptyElements: true,
      },
    },
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: 'link/verification',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'access_token',
          },
          user: false,
        },
        token: {
          maxAge: 60 * 60,
        },
        autoFetchUser: false,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question cannot be answered easily with just that. Improving performance can take a lot of analysis, can come from various places and is a broad topic.

Here is two of my answers on this subject (still relevant in your case):

- [How to increase speed performance in Nuxt with SSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71852756/how-to-increase-speed-performance-in-nuxt-with-ssr/71853523#71853523)
- [How to improve the LCP score of my Nuxt site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67317138/how-to-improve-the-lcp-score-of-my-nuxt-site/67319935#67319935)

---

Few things we can note on your `nuxt.config.js`:

- using `ssr: false` is basically fallback'ing to a pure SPA behavior, so the initial loading time may be quite slow (as always, it depends also on how you measure it)
- loading global CSS (`css` key) can be a penalty too
- all of the plugins you're loading are adding to the bundle-size (and hence, increase the loading time), maybe think to load some of them locally
- `ssr: false` is legacy, please use `mode: 'client'`
- also, checking for some smaller alternatives may be interesting too (are tho [37kB of JS](https://bundlephobia.com/package/particles@0.3.1) worth it?)

---

Other than this, there is also your overall code, some middleware, some 3rd party like Google analytics, the list goes on and on.
But I think you have a decent starting point with this.