# Avoid chaining critical requests in nuxt vuetify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I analyzed my site in GT Matrix and had a problem loading vueitfy fonts. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This part is not related to my code, we have this problem in Vueitfy. My problem is how to leave the files that Vuetify adds to run after the page loads and shortens the loading time of the site

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166329/8816585) and tell us if your issue is solved. Also, not sure what `leave the files that Vuetify adds` means. Regarding performance, please read this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71873576/8816585).